# Order_by with dbWritetable() for writing data in snowflake

Tags: r, odbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, r-dbi

While writing data into snowflake using dbWritetable() in R, order of data is getting messed up. Is there a way to maintain dataframe order while writing into snowflake?

Syntax using to write in snowflake:

`dbWriteTable(<connection>, <table_name>, <variable>, overwrite = TRUE, append = FALSE, verbose = TRUE, rownames = FALSE)`

Thanks

Comment: There's no notion of order in a relational table. Is there a field you could use to ORDER BY?

Comment: Said differently: the order that the data is *stored* (on insert or similar) is up to the DBMS, based on many metrics (including indices, data types/size, etc), and are typically completely uncontrollable by the end user (the administrator might be able to influence it, but that seems less common). Any query from a DBMS should assume that the order is arbitrary, perhaps even different each query (though that may not be strictly necessary), and enforce the order you need with `SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ...`.

Comment: Hi @FelipeHoffa , Thank you for the response, yes I am trying to write my data sorted by date.

Comment: Hi @r2evans , Thank you for the response, I will keep a note of that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize the comments section:

- When you do a `SELECT ... FROM ...` data is not guaranteed to come in any order. Such is the nature of SQL.
- If you want your data sorted by date (or any other field), make sure to request it so with `SELECT ... FROM ... ORDER BY ...`.